# How to pass a document as function argument(upload document)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, solidity-0.5.x

I am working on a project in solidity where I want to generate a SHA256 hash value for the document. So which means when I pass a file to a function the function should return the hash value.

can anyone please help me do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code (on-chain and off-chain) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document can be converted to a base64 encoded string. You can then hash the string to get the document hash. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: how to do it in solidity can you please help. I mean how to convert a document to base64

Comment: it is ideal you store only the hash in smart contract. since the data will be public. you can convert the document using javascript. You can then send the string to your contract. 
For more, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Hi, had a question. When I convert the file to base64 I get a big string(50 lines of string) when I pass the string as an argument to the function in solidity it can't handle that string, is there any way I can optimise the big string to short that it can be passed to the function in solidity.

Comment: You can hash the string off-chain. Store the hash in the contract. Whenever you want to verify the doc's validity, you can query the hash and then compare.